# Can I get the future unhandled promise rejection behaviour now?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, unhandled

> In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My pipeline passed when it should have failed and deployed a version that is crashing on launch. If Node.js would have exited with a non-zero exit code, the pipeline would have failed and the bad version wouldn't have been deployed.

Is there a way to make Node.js exit with a non-zero exit code when it encounters an unhandled promise rejection, that doesn't require me to wait for the future?

Comment: Look at this: https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-prevent-your-node-js-process-from-crashing-5d40247b8ab2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can, using [the `unhandledRejection` event on the `process` object](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection):

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason)
  process.exit(1)
});
```

Comment: Each part of the pipeline has a different entry point, so I would have to add this everywhere. The risk of forgetting this is the same as the risk of forgetting to put a catch block, which was the original problem. I was hoping for a flag, like `--exit-on-unhandled-promise-rejections` or even `--exit-on-warnings`, but I'm not finding anything like that. I would still have to remember to add the flag, but since that is done in one place (`package.json`), it would be much easier to remember.

Comment: You can put this in a file (say `handle_promise_rejections.js`) and use `node -r ./handle_promise_rejections.js <your_script.js>` to preload it.

Comment: Beautiful - thanks for your answer

Comment: I am actually stuck,where to run this command. My build is keep giving error Like this 
(node:23280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: NGCC failed.

please help

Comment: This answer is probably not a solution to your problem @ammadkhan.

Answer (score 14):

For `node` 12 and later:

```
node --unhandled-rejections=strict
```

Comment: I am actually stuck,where to run this command. My build is keep giving error Like this 
(node:23280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: NGCC failed.

please help

Answer (score 12):

I like setting these options via the environment variable:

```sh
export NODE_OPTIONS="--unhandled-rejections=strict"
```

Comment: where i can do this ? in windows environment variable or environment.ts file?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked on windows but an `.env` file will be a universal method of adding this to a project. You can also use https://www.rapidee.com/ for isolated cases

Answer (score 6):

You may also add an .npmrc file in your projects root directory.
Place the following content into the file:

```
node-options="--unhandled-rejections=strict"
```

Each time you execute an npm command the directories are parsed for the file and options from the file are read.

Comment: I am actually stuck,where to run this command. My build is keep giving error Like this 
(node:23280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: NGCC failed.

please help